# Does this prove that the force and momentum formulas are wrong?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum

Imagine someone is pressing a cube with his thumb and index finger, and there is no motion in the system.

Is the cube really under pressure?

If the cube is under pressure, how we can justify that pressure while nothing moves while the force and momentum formulas are based on motion (acceleration and velocity)?

Does this prove that the force and momentum formulas are wrong?

(If the definition I think I have read for force and momentum in physics is wrong, what is the correct definition?)

Comment: You can have force without momentum. F=ma is for net force

Comment: The force in F=ma is the net force. If you apply equal force in opposite directions, the formula predicts 0 acceleration (0 change in momentum) , just as you observed.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statics

Comment: If you will make cube of deformable material, you may see the difference between pressure presence and absence.

Comment: @DKNguyen Where is your reference?

Comment: People would probably like your question better if you would ask something like "Where in my thoughts is the mistake?" or "What in my (gedanken)experiment is wrong?" instead of implying that with such casual thought you might have proved almost 400 years of physics wrong.

Comment: @KooroshHeidarian Every mechanics textbook. It's the way F=ma is used or rather $\Sigma F=ma$. Free body diagrams, for example. You are mistaking F=ma for the definition of force (though I don't know what that is. After F=ma there is deformation strain-stress stuff which still isn't it. I think it's hidden away much deeper in physics).

Comment: @DKNguyen Can you tell me the correct definitions for force and momentum that are not based on motion?

Comment: @KooroshHeidarian No, like I said I think they are located much deeper in physics and I don't think you or I have enough background to comprehend them. It would have to include all the stuff that happens in subatomic particles too, and the apparent effects due to the strange nature of gravity too.

Comment: @DKNguyen The nice thing about F=ma is that the abstractions connect to the fundamental phenomena through very simple instruments. Spring+ruler measure force. Balance measures mass. Clock+ruler measure acceleration.

Comment: @JohnDoty Yeah. If I had to guess I would guess the fundamental definition is hidden away in the concept of action. At the point it doesn't look like anything recognizable unless you're already deep deep into the math of physics (Langrangian).  There's an easier to understand conceptual video on Youtube at PBS Spacetime about it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(physics)

Comment: @DKNguyen But that's not fundamental, it's a merely a mathematical model, chosen to represent the results of experiment and observation. Those are fundamental.

Comment: @JohnDoty In that sense no mathematical descriptors are, but there's closer and farther from fundamental which some would call more or less general.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that OP means Newton's second law by force formula, Note that it says
$$\mathbf{F}_\text{net}=m\mathbf{a}_\text{net}$$
In you situation, you are putting two forces from opposite sizes so that
$$\mathbf{F}_1+\mathbf{F}_2=m\mathbf{a}_\text{net}\\
\text{If}\ \ \mathbf{a}_\text{net}=0\rightarrow \ \mathbf{F}_1=-\mathbf{F}_2$$
So the cube is in rest means that the total force acting on it is simply zero. While the pressure is defined as
$$P =\frac{F_\perp}{A}$$
where $F_\perp$ is the perpendicular component of force to the surface. As you see, you will get non-zero pressure as long as you have this force like in your situation.

Comment: I think this does not answer the question.

Comment: @KooroshHeidarian I think it answers your questions (as written) quite precisely - in what way do you find this answer inadequate?

Answer (score 3):

Force does not require speed (or momentum). That is a common misconception. In your scenario, you have a stationary object, so Newton's 1st law applies:

$$\sum F=0\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad F_\text{press from the left}-F_\text{press from the right}=0,$$

where $F$ represents force. Nothing here tells us that forces only exist when there is speed (momentum). It just says that for this stationary scenario, all present force must exactly cancel out.

The reason that you tie force to momentum might be due to the momentum-version of Newton's 2nd law:

$$\sum F=\frac{\mathrm dp}{\mathrm dt},$$

where $p$ is momentum and $t$ time.

- But note firstly that this does not refer to *individual* forces but to *total force*.
- Secondly, note that this law also does not refer to the *momentum* but only to the *change in* momentum.

So there is really no reason to expect momentum and force to have any connection in general.

(You mention pressure, but that is simply force-per-area, $P=F/A$. My points above thus apply for that as well since you could just divide through by area $A$ in the mentioned equations).

Comment: @PaulT Good point.

Answer (score 2):

When you say that force and momentum formulas are based on motion, that is not completely true. For example, Hooke's law says that the degree to which a spring is stretched or compressed is proportional to the force applied to it- ie F=kx. There is no mention of motion in that equation.

You are overlooking the difference between the dynamic application of forces, which can result in acceleration, and forces in static equilibrium, in which their effects as causes of acceleration cancel out.

When you squeeze a cube between two fingers, the applied forces compress the cube to some extent until the resistive forces within the cube increase to the point at which they cancel the force of the fingers. The cube and fingers are then in a state of static equilibrium in which the accelerative effects of all the forces at work exactly cancel out.

Answer (score 1):

Your premise that force and momentum are based on motion is incorrect. The equation $$\mathbf{F_{net}}=m\mathbf{a}$$ says that the acceleration that an object experiences is proportional to the force applied and inversely proportional to its mass. In your case, the net force is zero because the two forces are equal in magnitude and opposite in direction, hence there is no net force and the block does not accelerate. If it starts in a state of rest it will remain at rest, so no motion.
This also implies that the momentum of the block is zero.
However, this does not imply that the pressure on the object is zero. The pressure is defined, as others have stated above, by $$P=\frac{F_{perp}}{A}$$ where the subscript indicated the component of the force perpendicular to the area on which the force is applied. Since you are applying two forces on two opposite sides of a block, and since pressure is a scalar, not a vector, these two pressures add, giving you a total non-zero pressure on the block.
Think about a rock on the bottom of the ocean. If it is resting there, the net sum of forces on it must be zero, and indeed it is, but it is still under extreme pressure due to the water surrounding it.